# Time Issue in ios

Tags: ios, nsdate

I want to display the date in format of Mon Sep 1 at 4:41 Pm. Can any one tell me the format for this string? I am using this format but it is not working for me

```
NSDate* date= [format dateFromString:@"DD MMM dd 'at' HH:mm"];
```

Comment: See the docs for the format specifiers.

Comment: I recommend you use `localizedStringFromDate:dateStyle:timeStyle:` although you can use custom specifiers if you prefer. If you use your own text (like `at`) it will make translation / localisation much harder.

Comment: Bookmark this http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `NSDateFormatter` to accomplish this.

The issue is you are passing in the format string in the wrong place. You need to set it using the `setDateFormat:` method. Then call `stringFromDate:` to run the `NSDate` through the formatter and return the string you want.

The `MMM` format specifier will give you the abbreviated month, which will be one of these:

> Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec

The `EEE` format specifier will give you the abbreviated weekday, which will be one of these:

> Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun

Answer (score 0):

Given an NSDate object "myDate":

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM d 'at' h:mm a"];
NSString *result = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: myDate];
```